# Spring Boot pom set up

Tags: spring-boot

I am starting to learn spring boot and I'm already struggling to find why I keep getting this error package `org.springframework.boot` does not exist.

I tried adding `-web` to the artifactId.

It looked like this:

```xml
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
```

This is after:

```xml
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
```

This is my pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.yuriney</groupId>
    <artifactId>vendas</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my class:

```java
package io.github.yuriney;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VendasApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VendasApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might install JDK 17 locally and adjust your JDK version in pom.xm, then try it again.

```
    <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```